# Invalid Attribute Error

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am using JavaMe.

Every time I attempt to initialize a List object I receive the following error:

The value for attribute null is not in the proper format

I am using Eclipse and JRE 6 on Mac OSX Lion.

Here is my simple code:

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

public class ListTest extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

private Display display;
private List optionsItem;
private Command exit;

public ListTest(){
    optionsItem = new List("List types of Item", Choice.IMPLICIT);

}

protected void startApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        optionsItem.append("TextField",null);
        optionsItem.addCommand(exit);
        optionsItem.setCommandListener(this);
        display.setCurrent(optionsItem);
}

public void pauseApp() {

}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
  notifyDestroyed();
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing your member variables correctly?

The Command object is never initialized, i.e. 'exit' is null

```
private Command exit;
```

Comment: Parameterless constructor for List doesn't exist. But yes I bet the null Command is the problem

Answer (score 0):

*The value for attribute...* error seems to point to some problem in [MIDlet JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28file_format%29).

It looks like your MIDlet fails to install or launch even before the buggy code with uninitialized command [pointed to in previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295157/invalid-attribute-error/7295570#7295570) gets a chance to execute.

To debug issues like that I'd use the simplest code that could possibly work. Like say this:

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

public class SmokeTest extends MIDlet {

    protected void startApp() {
        Display display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        Form form = new Form("form");
        form.addCommand(new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1));
        form.setCommandListener(new CommandListener() {
            public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
                notifyDestroyed();
            }
        });
        display.setCurrent(form);
    }

    protected void pauseApp() { }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
}
```

If MIDlet installs and launches OK, above code will display a Form with title "form" and with command "Exit". If that doesn't happen, it's better to study Eclipse documentation to figure what's wrong with J2ME config settings.